# Right-continuity of a function defined by $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let $h(u)=\limsup_{r\downarrow u,r\in \mathbb{Q}}f(r).$

Is $h$ right-continuous? Why?

Attempt: fix $\epsilon>0,u_0 \in \mathbb{R},$ then we know that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\forall v \in [u_0,u_0+\delta/2],h(u_0)+\epsilon \geq \sup_{r\in [u_0,u_0+\delta]\cap \mathbb{Q}}f(r)\geq \sup_{r\in [v,v+\delta/2]\cap \mathbb{Q}}f(r)\geq h(v)$$

How to continue from here? I am problem proving the other inequality: $h(v) \geq h(u_0)-\epsilon$

Before downvoting or closing, would you care to explain why, a clear question with a clear attempt, and explained where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D= \{ {1 \over n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and define $f(x) = 1_D(x)$.
Then $h(u) = 1_{\{0\}}(u)$, which is not right continuous at $u=0$.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ has no discontinuity points of second kind (limit exist at right and left of every point of the domain), then the result should hold true?

Comment: If $f$ has right and left limits then it is continuous.

Comment: Sorry I meant the limits at right and left of $f$ exist at every point $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ (not necessarly equal) and $f$ is bounded on every $[u,v]\cap \mathbb{Q}$